# Database design for sharing photos site?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, sharing, photos

I am using php and mysql. If I want to do a sharing photos website, whats the best database design for upload and display photos. This is what I have in mind:

```
domain:
  |_> photos
  |_> user
```

Logged in user will upload photo in 
    [http://www.domain.com/user/upload.php]

The photos are stored in filesystems, and the path-to-photos stored in database. So, in my photos folder would be like: photos/userA/subfolders+photos, photos/userB/subfolders+photos, photos/userC/subfolders+photos etc

Public/others people may view his photo in:
    [http://www.domain.com/photos/user/?photoid=123]

where 123 is the photoid, from there, I will query from database to fetch the path and display the image.

My questions:

1. Whats the best database design for photo-sharing website (like flickr)?
2. Will there be any problems if I keep creating new folder in "photos" folder. What if hundreds of thousands users registered? Whats the best practices
3. What size of photos should I keep? Currently I only stored thumbnail (100x100) and (max) 1600x1200 px photos.
4. What others things I should take note when developing photos-sharing website?

Comment: I am new to this site, I though the best answer will be picked automatically based on numbers of "up" votes. I am sorry.

Comment: no, you must choose the answer you find the most helpful. people will be more helpful if they see you participating in the site the correct way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1 - At a minimum your database should consist of

```
users: user_id, user_name, pw_hash, salt
photos: photo_id, user_id, photo_path
```

fields would be added for extra functionality you wanted (tags, last_seen, photo_upload_date, photo_views, etc...)

2 - Dont prematurely optimize. i would go with adding a users/username folder for each user and dumping the users photos in there.

3 - i recommend keeping the original size, thumbnail, and a size that is suited for your site. so if your layout holds a photo with max width of 850px resize all photos to a max 850px wide. If youre layout changes you can use the original picture and resize them to the new size.

4 - there is an excellent answer on SO somewhere about image upload security but i cant find it. ill keep looking.

think about using a CDN: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72369/whats-the-best-cdn-for-image-hosting-on-a-high-volume-web-site

good talk on scalabilty, the section on thumbnails would be good for you to watch: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZW5_eEKEC28. this video talks about a file-per-directory limit in ext3 filesystems you may be interested in.